# Attempting headless boot - GRUB keeps coming up and preventing startup

Tags: boot, grub2

I've installed Ubuntu 13.10 on a Mac Mini I'm trying to get the computer to boot without any attached peripherals or displays. For whatever reason, GRUB always comes up on every boot, and it displays two options: "Ubuntu" and "Advanced Options for Ubuntu".
How can I stop this menu from interrupting the boot?
I've already tried "GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true", and it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable you have to set in `/etc/default/grub` is not GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET, but GRUB_TIMEOUT and GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT so use these:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```